# In batch, how to capture a name of iterated folder using for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

From a batch script, using a for-loop, I would like to capture only the name of the iterated folder as in the example below:

```
    SET _source=C:\Users\userId

    FOR /D %%i in (%_source%\*) DO (
       ECHO nameOfIteratedFolder=...
    )
```

For example if the iterated folder is `C:\Users\userId\Desktop` I would like to capture only the **Desktop** name in a variable `nameOfIteratedFolder`.

If I use `%%i` parameter I get all the path of the Desktop folder: `C:\Users\userId\Desktop`

Thank to all.

Comment: Type `for /?`. The info is repeated in `call /?` as well.

Comment: Additionally, if `%%i` is output to `DO` then it must exist. There is therefore no need to perform an `IF EXIST` on it!

Comment: I hope, you have opened already a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), executed `for /?` and read carefully the output help from top of first page to bottom of last page to understand `for /D %%I in ("%UserProfile%\*") do echo Current folder is: "%%~nxI"`. See also the list of predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). Compare the result with `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%UserProfile%" /AD /B 2^>nul') do echo Current folder is: "%%I"`. You see most likely differences as __FOR /D__ ignores hidden folders.

Comment: @Mark I had already consulted ```for /?``` but evidently I had not understood well the use of modifiers. @Compo I corrected the code: originally the foor-loop was performed on an arbitrary list. @Mofi your comment answered my question. Thank you. Thanks to everyone for participating.